# Custom attribute containing whether or not there's a relation between models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two models: User and Event.

Both have a polymorphic many to many relationship to each other.

Is there any way when I do `Event::all()`

to `$appends` a `getJoinedAttribute()` that returns true if the `Auth::user()` has a relation to each Event in the list?

```
    public function getJoinedAttribute() {
        return $this->whereHas('users', function($query) {
           $query->where('users.id', Auth::user()->id);
        })->count() > 0 ? true : false;
```

I guess I need something similar to this.

Comment: this function you added in Event Modal ?

Answer (score 1):

Here I try with my system:

```
In my Order Modal:

public function scopeOrderStatus($query, $status, $newOrder = null)
{
    if ($newOrder !== null) {
        return $query->where(function($filter) use ($status, $newOrder){
            $filter->where('status', $status)->whereDate('created_at', $newOrder);
        })->count();
    }
    return $query->where('status', $status)->count();
}

in Your Controller to access :

$pendingConfirmOrders = Order::orderStatus(1);
```